# Map entry key in java

Tags: java, dictionary, equals

I'm trying to debug a problem I've on a script, I'm newly to Java I think it's a simplest thing but I need to understand. This :

```
for( Map.Entry<String,int[]> entry : this.indexMap.entrySet())
{
     if( !entry.getKey().equals("nickname"))
     {
         System.out.print("'"+ entry.getKey() +"' contains "+ entry.getKey().length() +" chars");
         System.out.print("'"+ name +"' contains "+ name.length() +" chars");
     }
     else if( entry.getKey().trim().equals("nickname") )
     {
         System.out.print("Yes are sames");
     } 
}
```

For a String name = "nickname", displays me that :

```
18:56:15 [INFOS] 'nickname' contains 94 chars

18:56:15 [INFOS] 'nickname' contains 8 chars
```

I'm trying to understand this.

The problem is `entry.getKey()` returns the same thing as my string name, but not really the same. In first test, we saw the two vars are different, so the print is did, but the twos vars have the same value, and not the same length. In the else-if, I tried to remove spaces but not printed so where are from these 94 chars?

https://code.google.com/p/imdbparsers/source/browse/trunk/imdb+parsers/src/imdb/parsers/xmltosql/NamedParameterStatement.java?r=6

Is the code, methods concerned are

```
private String parse(String query) 

private int[] getIndexes(String name)
```

line 161 et 89
This for loop i've in mine is only to debug the

```
 int[] indexes = (int[]) indexMap.get(name);
```

Returns always null

The query string is :

```
SELECT COUNT(`account_id`) AS `total` FROM `game_accounts` WHERE `nickname`=:nickname
```

Comment: Do not use smilies on SO. I have put this comment so that next time you will take care for this.

Comment: Where does the `name` variable come from? This code confuses me.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: 'cause them's the rules.

Comment: Ignore the smiles issues and please try to clarify your question. What exactly are you asking here? Please clarify before your question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

```
entry.getKey().equals("nickname")
```

and

```
entry.getKey().trim().equals("nickname")
```

is `trim()`.

The first take in account the spaces and the second not.

It's because they are a loop on a map: to find the 'bad' keys...

Comment: But the first statement of his has a `!` operator. In all his question is quite confusing.

Comment: i can put you the fully code interact with these variables, but is long. it's a part of an public code source found on internet.

Comment: Put more to help us to help you.

Comment: It's very confusing. Why did it enter the `if` condition although `entry.getKey()` returns `"nickname"`

Comment: I presume this code won't work, and it's a debug code to take a look into the maps used.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you reverse your if clauses you might get something that behaves more like what you are expecting, although it is somewhat unclear what you are asking. Comparing keys as the first clause in the if block makes the code simpler.

```
if( entry.getKey().trim().equals("nickname") ) 
{
     System.out.print("Yes are sames");
}
else
{
     System.out.print("'"+ entry.getKey() +"' contains "+ entry.getKey().length() +" chars");
     System.out.print("'"+ name +"' contains "+ name.length() +" chars");
}
```